# Syntax to watch modal and execute function once shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, modal-dialog

I've seen this type of thing asked, and found some good leads, however none of them work in my environment so I'm wondering if there's a more generic way. I have a modal with an id assigned:

```
<div id="sandbox" class="modal-header modal-header-interaction" ng-init="init()">
```

The ng-init calls into the controller fine, so I could just set the listener there, but I haven't been able to determine the right syntax. So far I've tried this:

```
    $( "#sandbox" ).on('shown', function(){
        alert("Shown!");
    });
```

This:

```
    $('#sandbox').hasClass('in', function(){
        alert("Shown!");
    });
```

This:

```
$(window).on("shown", function(e) {
    $('#sandbox').modal('show');
    alert('OK');
});
```

...I feel like I'm very close here, does anyone have an angle on where I might be going wrong?

EDIT

Some more info:

These modals get created from a factory where:

```
 var dialogOptions = {
     templateUrl: 'views/sandbox/template/custom-plan/custom-sandbox-model-window.html',
     controller: 'customPlanDataCtrl'
 }
```

And the call is:

```
ModalDialogFactory.showDialog(dialogOptions);
```

The modal dialog factory returns this:

```
   return {
        showDialog: function (modalOptions) {
            var modalConfig = {};
            angular.extend(modalConfig, modalDialogDefaults, modalOptions);
            modalInstance = $modal.open(modalConfig);
            modalInstance.rendered.then(() => {
                alert('OK');
            });
            return modalInstance.result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I am going to recommend what I always do in these situations: toss jQuery and just use AngularJS if you are going to use AngularJS. Both jQuery and AngularJS are DOM manipulation frameworks and you will drive yourself crazy trying to make them work together. The Angular team created UI Bootstrap to have native AngularJS directives for you to use, including a modal that has opened and rendered (among other) events. It would be perfect to implement in this situation (and you can explore the other UI Bootstrap directives while you're at it).

Comment: I'm not married to jQuery...do you know the syntax to accomplish this in angularjs?

Comment: Is there any way you could add a directive to your modal template? If you could, then you could wrap its `link` function in a `$timeout` and that would fire once the directive is rendered. I believe the rendering of the directive should correspond with the rendering of the modal. You could do something similar with a component which has a very clearly defined life cycle with events, but components were not added until v1.5.

Comment: Thanks for the lead, I'll try that angle.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own trigger

```
(function($) {
    $.each(['show', 'hide'], function(i, ev) {
        var el = $.fn[ev];
        $.fn[ev] = function() {
            this.trigger(ev);
            return el.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[Follow this link](https://jsfiddle.net/zohmynp5/)

[Source](https://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-trigger-custom-event-show-hide-element/)

Comment: I think the trigger idea is it, but while with your specific implementation I can watch the show and hide events come in, they all seem to be related to the spinner that appears while the modal data is being gathered, I never see any reference to the modal itself...is there a way to target the modal specifically?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment, I highly recommend using native AngularJS implementation such as that provided by [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). Here is a very simple implementation of a modal (`$uibModal`) showing how you can take specific action when the modal is opened, rendered, and closed/dismissed.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('ctrl', ($scope, $uibModal) => {
    $scope.showModal = () => {
      console.log('showing modal...');
      var modalOptions = {
        backdrop: 'static',
        templateUrl: 'modalSample.html',
        controller: ($scope, $uibModalInstance) => {
          $scope.Ok = () => $uibModalInstance.close('can use any primitive or object here');
        }
      };

      var modal = $uibModal.open(modalOptions);
      debugger;
      modal.opened.then(() => {
        console.log('modal opened');
        });
      modal.rendered.then(() => {
        console.log('modal rendered');
        });
      modal.result.then((data) => {
          console.log('modal closed with response: ' + data);
        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.log('modal dismissed');
        });
    };
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" style="padding: 20px;">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showModal()">Show Modal</button>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="modalSample.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">Modal Sample</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      Here is the body of the modal. Press [Esc] to dismiss this modal or close it using the button to observe the difference between closing and dimissing.
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="Ok()">OK</button>
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the input @Lex - let me tinker with this approach!

Comment: Okay, I've tracked down where this occurs and tried adding the modal.rendered bit, but I still don't see the alert kick off...I've added some additional information into my original question for reference so you can see how this is happening.

Comment: One more piece of information, it looks like the rendered options might not even be present in the modal instance here...when I set a breakpoint after 'modalInstance = $modal.open(modalConfig)' then inspect the modalInstance var, I see 'close', 'dismiss', 'opened', and 'result', but no 'rendered'. Am I looking in the wrong place maybe?

Comment: Odd, do you see the same if you run the snippet that I provided? I just added a `debugger;` and when I open Chrome's dev tools and run the snippet I can examine the `modal` object and `rendered` is definitely there. You're using the UI Bootstrap stuff, right?

Comment: I thought so but now I'm beginning to wonder...I'm new to this project, so let me do some digging around and see if it could be something else.

Comment: It looks like we are using this: <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>   If I go to the Maven repository and look at the angular ui bootstrap it's called angularjs-ui-bootstrap_sjs0.6_2.11, so I think maybe this is my problem...unfortunately I don't know if I have the option of changing this.

Comment: Okay, I think I know what the problem might be...we are using AngularJS, and ui-bootstrap-tpls.js version 0.12.0 - I'm thinking the rendered option is in a later version. Do you happen to know if there is a version of ui-bootstrap-tpls.js that is supported by AngularJS *and* also supports the rendered option?

Comment: The 2.5.0 version that I used in the snippet above is supported by AngularJS and includes the rendered promise.

Comment: Strange...I upgraded even to 0.13.0 (from 0.12.0) and the $modal injections stopped working with the error: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $modal <- ConfirmationModalFactory <- $auth    If there is a way to make these work together though that would be awesome, since the rendered option appears to be my solution

Comment: Okay, I think the problem is that our version of angular is 1.2.16...to use even ui-bootstrap 0.13.0 we would need to update to 1.3.x at least, which I've been told we aren't doing in the short term. I don't suppose you know of any other way around the modal issue?

Comment: I don't. We've always used `$uibModal` or `mdDialog`.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll push for the upgrade